# Searching for a keyword across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I have a set of names of schools stored in each row in my schools table. the same table has four different category columns which store the names of the subjects they offer. I want to enable functionality where the user conducts a search on the table to find out all the names of the schools which teach a particular subject (for eg: physics). The name of the particular subject could be stored in any of the four subject columns. Please suggest a mysqli_/mysql_ query to conduct such a search or if you may so please, suggest a PHP script that would achieve the above functionality.

Comment: Don't splay an array of subjects across columns; create another table.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple query using OR in WHERE clause and passing your search string.

```
SELECT school_name
FROM schools
WHERE Subject1 = 'Physics'
OR Subject2 = 'Physics'
OR Subject3 = 'Physics'
OR Subject4 = 'Physics'
```

You can parameterize the search string and pass on to this query.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the columns and use "like":

```
SELECT school_name
FROM schools
WHERE Subject1||Subject2||Subject3 like '%Physics%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT school_name
FROM schools
WHERE 'Physics' IN (Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4);
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? It may not be the most efficient approach, but it's valid regardless. Better than concatenation offered by another poster.